# Why don't save me file in dist directory in TS

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, nestjs

I create a file which i save in my `./src/report/files/` using `exceljs` library like this:

```
workBook.xlsx.writeFile(`./src/report/files/${fileName}.xlsx`);
```

so, my file is in physically way saved in the above directory,

but when I try to download this file via this path:

```
const filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'files', `${fileName}.xlsx`);
```

(this path is: `/.../c/.../.../.../.../.../dist/report/files/SomeFileName.xlsx`)

i get an error like this:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/.../c/.../.../.../.../.../dist/report/files/SomeFileName.xlsx'
```

so I look into my `dist` folder and I saw that I do not have my `files` folder in `report`, can someone tell me why and how can I save the file into this directory and properly download my files?

thanks for any help

ps. I'm using NestJS and Typescript

Comment: Three dots? I've never seen this syntax. Captain?

Comment: i edit is personally to hide it in SO

Answer (score 1):

Typescript will tranpile your `.ts` files to `.js` and move those to the `outDir` specified (usually `dist/`), but it won't move other file types, besides `.js` and `.json`. If you're looking to move them, you can write a `postbuild` script that makes use of your command line (something like `mv ./src/**/*.xslx ./dist`), but what would probably be better/more stable is to make a `files` directory in your project root and instead of using `path.join(__dirname, 'files', '${filename}.xlsx')` use `path.join(process.cwd(), 'files', '${filename}.xlsx')`

Comment: but, `process.cwd()` will work properly when i deploy my project on remote server? I mean, this will download properly my file from remote server?

Comment: `process.cwd()` refers to the directory where the process was started from. _Most_ of the time, this is your project root, so it should work without a problem

Comment: Using `__dirname` is in most cases more reliable than `process.cwd()`

Comment: But not when it comes to files that are not moved via your compiler/bundler. That's specifically why I suggested using `process.cwd()` and using a project root directory for the xlsx files

Comment: so, summarizing, to download files i must use `process.cwd()` and folder where is my all files that i must download via `process.cwd()` must be in the `src/here`?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel can you confirm?